# Gedit do not display PHP (Lampp)

Tags: php, gedit

I use Apache 2 server with Lampp. Php 5 and MySql are correctly installed (under Ubuntu).

The server and all applications are started. But when I want to open a .php doc, it is empty. When I'm using firefox with locahost to check, the .php works fine.

Is it Gedit or PHP configuration? Should I ensure that PHP is in any manner used by Gedit?

Thank you for your response

Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are opening the file under var/www/html

Comment: Thank you I also tried the other solutions, but yours was the relevant one to my case. How is it that php only works under this folder and not the desk ? Is it gedit or apache?

Comment: it's an apache thing. Pretty much this folder is connected to the server.

Answer (score 1):

you probably don't have the permission to read your file created by apache

try this

```
cd your_directory_name_for_apache

sudo chmod -R 775 .
```

then try again

if it doesn't work try to reinstall `gedit` or simply install `sublime`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit
```

this will install sublime

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

then open it with sublime

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another editor to open the php files such as nano.
I think it is unlikely that gedit is failing to open the files. You could try reinstalling gedit:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit
```